# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. : grid view inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, .net

gridview is placed in repeater,
it is showing error on itemdata bound

code,

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptSearchResult" runat="server" 
                OnItemDataBound="rptSearchResult_ItemDataBound">
          <HeaderTemplate>
         <table border="0">
             <tr>
                 <td> Cost Page</td>
                 <td> Cost Page Description</td>
                 <td> Vendor Name</td>
                 <td> Bill Type</td>
             </tr>
      </HeaderTemplate>

      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td> <%# Eval("CostPage")%></td>
               <td><%# Eval("CostPageDescription")%> </td>
               <td> <%# Eval("VendorName")%> </td>
               <td><%# Eval("BillType")%> </td>
         </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>
               <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" >
                   <Columns>  
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                     <ItemTemplate> 
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>              
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemId" HeaderText="Item ID"/>                    
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemDescription"  HeaderText="Item Description"/>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="BrandCode"   HeaderText="Brand Code"/>                    

                    </Columns> 

               </asp:GridView>  </td>
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>

      <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
      </FooterTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>
```

in .cs file,

```
    protected void rptSearchResult_ItemDataBound(
       object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gd = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvDetails");


        details e1 = new details();
        e1.itemid= 1;
        e1.itemdesc = "item1";
        e1.brandcode = "BBB";

        List<details> employees = new List<details>();
        employees.Add(e1);

        gd.DataSource = employees;
        gd.DataBind();
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `gd` object weather it is null or not than execute your certain conditions. Thus the code should be like below:

```
GridView gd = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvDetails");

if(gd != null) {
  gd.DataSource = employees;
  gd.DataBind();
}
```

**Edit:**
The error is coming because the name in the `DataField="ItemDescription"` of `asp:BoundField` doesn't match the datasource employees properties which you have specified at the time of databind. The markup code should be

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="itemdesc"  HeaderText="Item Description"/>
```

Comment: want to know why it is coming as null. I have gridview in repeater.

Comment: i changed that , but didn't fix, the itemdatabound event will be executed on binding the repeater to it's datasource.

Comment: so is the gd is always coming null or anything else?

Comment: @user2543573, i think the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by adding following check:

```
 if( (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)) 
  {  
    //Non-null value for grid
  }
```

Now, the gridview is non-null value.